# Expected number of returns to zero in a symmetric random walk - closed form

Tags: combinatorics, random-walk

The expected number of returns of a symmetric random walk is given by

$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k} / 2^{2k} -1$

The exercise is to compute an explicit form for this. I tried to do this in the following way:

$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k} / 2^{2k}= \sum_{k=0}^n 1/(2 \pi i) \int_{|z|=0.5} 1/2^{2k}(1+z)^{2k}/ z^{k+1} dz $

$=1/(2 \pi i) \int_{|z|=0.5}\sum_{k=0}^n  1/2^{2k}((1+z)^2)^k/ z^{k+1}dz $

From here one can use geometric series and simplifying the double ratio  to arrive at
$1/(2 \pi i) \int_{|z|=0.5}  1/2^{2n}((1+z)^{2n+2}- 2^{2n+2} z^{n+1})/ ((z-1)^2z^{n+1})dz$

The monomial in the numerator with power n has a coefficient of 2n+2 choose n. All other terms vanish when applying the residue theore. Hence the result should be $\binom{2n+2}{n}$. But I know from the lecture that it is not (also from the asymptotic behavior) I cant figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Presumably you are looking for something a little bigger than $\sqrt{n}$

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty{2k\choose k}x^k=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}.~$ See also [central binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient).

Comment: A shorter solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2183730).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer that repeats  some of the material from the question
but typeset slightly differently.

We seek to compute
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {2k\choose k} 2^{-2k}.$$

Introduce the integral representation
$${2k\choose k}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{2k}}{z^{k+1}} \; dz.$$

This gives for the sum 
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z} \sum_{k=0}^n
\frac{(1+z)^{2k}}{z^k} 2^{-2k} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z} \sum_{k=0}^n
\left(\frac{(1+z)^2}{4z}\right)^k \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z}
\frac{((1+z)^2/4/z)^{n+1}-1}{(1+z)^2/4/z-1} \; dz
\\ = \frac{4}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{((1+z)^2/4/z)^{n+1}-1}{(1-z)^2} \; dz.$$

The second term in the difference  does not contribute and we are left
with
$$\frac{4}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}
((1+z)^2/4/z)^{n+1} \; dz
\\ = \frac{4}{4^{n+1}}\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} (1+z)^{2n+2} \; dz .$$

Extracting coefficients from this we obtain
$$\frac{1}{2^{2n}} \sum_{q=0}^n {2n+2\choose q} (n-q+1).$$

Here we have calculated
$$[z^n] \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} (1+z)^{2n+2}$$
by  matching  the  first $n+1$  powers  $z^q$  up  to $z^n$  from  the
polynomial with  the corresponding  power $z^{n-q}$ from  the rational
term.

There are two pieces here, the first is:
$$\frac{n+1}{2^{2n}} \sum_{q=0}^n {2n+2\choose q}
= \frac{n+1}{2^{2n}} 
\frac{1}{2}
\left(2^{2n+2} - {2n+2\choose n+1}\right).$$

The second piece is:
$$- \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \sum_{q=0}^n {2n+2\choose q} \times q
= - \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \sum_{q=1}^n {2n+2\choose q} \times q
\\ = - \frac{2n+2}{2^{2n}} \sum_{q=1}^n {2n+1\choose q-1}
= - \frac{2n+2}{2^{2n}} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n+1\choose q}
\\ = - \frac{2n+2}{2^{2n}} 
\frac{1}{2}
\left(2^{2n+1} - 2 {2n+1\choose n}\right).$$

The nonbinomial term in the first piece is
$$\frac{n+1}{2^{2n}} 
\frac{1}{2} 2^{2n+2} = 2n+2$$
and in the second piece
$$- \frac{2n+2}{2^{2n}} 
\frac{1}{2} 2^{2n+1} = -(2n+2)$$
so these two cancel.

This leaves
$$\frac{n+1}{2^{2n}}
\left(2{2n+1\choose n}
- \frac{1}{2}{2n+2\choose n+1}\right)$$
which is
$$\frac{n+1}{2^{2n}}
\left(2 \frac{n+1}{2n+2} {2n+2\choose n+1}
- \frac{1}{2}{2n+2\choose n+1}\right)
\\= \frac{n+1}{2^{2n}} \frac{1}{2} {2n+2\choose n+1}
= \frac{n+1}{2^{2n+1}} {2n+2\choose n+1}.$$

Apparently this method is due to Egorychev.

Comment: Thank you, I do not understand the step how the integral is evaluated. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks. I added a line that shows the use of the coefficient extraction operator $[z^n]$ for power series.

Comment: +1, though you have to subtract $1$ to get to the original question