# Help with a combinatoric formula

Tags: combinatorics

Anyone can help solve th following? $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {2n} \\ 
  n 
\end{array}} \right)$  means $2n$ chooses $n$. Thanks!

$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {2k} \\ 
  k 
\end{array}} \right){2^{ - 2k}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{(2k)!}}{{k!k!}}{2^{ - 2k}}}  = \frac{{(2n)!}}{{n!n!}}(2n + 1){2^{ - 2n}} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {2n} \\ 
  n 
\end{array}} \right){2^{ - 2n}}(2n + 1)$

The report from [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B((2k)!)%2F(k!k!)2%5E(-2k),k%3D0,n%5D-((2n)!)%2F(n!n!)(2n%2B1)2%5E(-2n)) shows they indeed equal.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about induction? The base case $n = 0$ is easily verified. Then

\begin{align}
\binom{2n}{n}2^{-2n}(2n+1) + \binom{2n+2}{n+1}2^{-2n-2} &= \binom{2n+2}{n+1}2^{-2n-2}\biggl[\frac{4(n+1)^2}{2n+2} + 1\biggr] \\
&= \binom{2n+2}{n+1}2^{-2n-2}\bigl(2n+2+1\bigr)
\end{align}

is the induction step.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get a bijection but it seems kind of complicated, i will definitely be interested if someone has a bijection for it. Using generation functions is easy tho.
Just noticing that the LHS is a convolution of central binomial coefficients and powers of $4$ and so $$\sum _{k = 0}^n\binom{2k}{k}2^{2n-2k}=[x^n]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\frac{1}{1-4x}=[x^n](\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}+\frac{4x}{\sqrt{1-4x}^3})=([x^n]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}+[x^n]\frac{4x}{\sqrt{1-4x}^3})=\binom{2n}{n}+2n\binom{2n}{n},$$
where the last step is just noticing that $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}})'=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-4x}^3}.$ 
My approach to a bijection is noticing that $\binom{[2k]}{k}2^{2n-2k}$ can be realized as a path from $(0,0)$ to $(k,k)$ plus a path that can be reached outside or inside the $n\times n$ box. I will add more details soon.