# Proof of $\sum_{k=0}^n{ \binom{2k}{k} 2^{2n-2k} } = (2n+1) \binom{2n}{n} = \frac{n+1}{2} \binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs, catalan-numbers

I found some combinatorial identities in my old notebooks, but I cannot recall how I derived them. Can anyone help provide the most elementary/elegant proofs for the following identity? Specifically, the connection between the summation and either of the two closed-form expressions.

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n{ \binom{2k}{k} 2^{2n-2k} } = (2n+1) \binom{2n}{n} = \frac{n+1}{2} \binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}
$$

Some specific cases written out for some simple visualization: ($n=0$ through $n=3$)
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{0}{0} 2^{0} &= 1\binom{0}{0} = \frac{1}{2}\binom{2}{1} \\
\binom{0}{0} 2^{2} + \binom{2}{1} 2^{0} &= 3\binom{2}{1}  = \frac{2}{2}\binom{4}{2} \\
\binom{0}{0} 2^{4} + \binom{2}{1} 2^{2} + \binom{4}{2} 2^{0} &= 5\binom{4}{2} = \frac{3}{2}\binom{6}{3}\\
\binom{0}{0} 2^{6} + \binom{2}{1} 2^{4} + \binom{4}{2} 2^{2} + \binom{6}{3} 2^{0} &= 7\binom{6}{3} = \frac{4}{2}\binom{8}{4}
\end{align}
$$

EDIT: I should specify that I have already found an inductive proof, but it is not satisfying to me. I am specifically looking for a bijective/double-counting proof ideally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help with a combinatoric formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183730/help-with-a-combinatoric-formula)

Comment: I want to emphasize the "elementary/elegant proof" part. I understand that induction proofs aren't necessarily not fitting, but I haven't found an elegant induction proof that feels very satisfying.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a bijective/double counting proof ideally, but I posted the question precisely because I have not found one.

Comment: Now found [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3567739). But it seems already familiar to you ;)

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaa I already have this bookmarked, my goodness

Comment: I had forgotten that I had answered the question that metamorphy cited. At least it is a different answer, so there is some added value to my answer for this question.

Comment: @Zhuli: It would be nice if you added the inductive proof that you have already, so that someone else does not post the same proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A Couple of "Common" Series**

We have the [Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty 4^kx^k=\frac1{1-4x}\tag1
$$
and the [Generating Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) for the [Central Binomial Coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}x^k=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}\tag2
$$
Equation $(2)$ is the [Generalized Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) applied to $\binom{-1/2}{k}=\left(-\frac14\right)^k\binom{2k}{k}$, which is shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/755871).

---

**Using the Cauchy Product**

We get the product of the preceding functions by taking half the derivative of $(2)$ and adjusting the index:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k+1}2\binom{2k+2}{k+1}x^k=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}^3}\tag3
$$
The [Cauchy Product Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) then says that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2k}{k}4^{n-k}
&=\frac{n+1}2\binom{2n+2}{n+1}\tag4\\[3pt]
&=(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}\tag5
\end{align}
$$

Comment: A different solution. Not elementary, but somewhat elegant.

Comment: As the sequence of sums in the question is the convolution of two "common" series, this seemed like the way to go.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this answer, so I assume the downvote has something to do with something unrelated to the answer, unless the downvoter cares to comment.

Answer (score 1):

Proving the equality between the two closed form is easier:

$$\begin{align*}
(2n+1)\binom{2n}n &=(2n+1)\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}\\
&= \frac{(2n+1)!}{n!n!}\\
&= \frac{(n+1)^2}{(2n+2)}\cdot\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+1)!}\\
&= \frac{n+1}{2}\binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}
\end{align*}$$

By induction, consider the $n+1$ case of the summation form and the second closed-form,

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{2k}{k}2^{2(n+1)-2k} &= 2^2\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2k}{k}2^{2n-2k} + \binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}2^0\\
&= 2^2\cdot \underbrace{\frac{n+1}{2} \binom{2(n+1)}{n+1)}}_{\text{by induction hypothesis}} + \binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}2^0\\
&= [2(n+1)+1]\binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}
\end{align*}$$